# resteasy: @QueryParam to parse nested array structure

Tags: java, ajax, rest, resteasy, tabulator

I'm using a javascript library called tabulator to display data inside tables on the client side.

The Tabulator js library provides a feature to encode a representation of `filters` in the query parameters of an ajax request. For example, here's what the query params look like:

`https://host/myEndpoint?size=10&page=1&filters%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=username&filters%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=like&filters%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=filteredBy`

Here's the same url decoded:

`https://host/myEndpoint?size=10&page=1&filters[0][field]=username&filters[0][type]=like&filters[0][value]=filteredBy`

If possible, I'd like to have a Resteasy endpoint like this:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/myEndpoint")
 @Consumes("application/json")
 @Produces("application/json")
 public Response myEndpoint(@QueryParam("page") Integer page,
                            @QueryParam("size") Integer size,
                            @QueryParam("filters") List<Filter> filters) {
```

resteasy interprets `page` and `size` no problem, but `filters` is always a list of size 0.

My `Filter` bean has 3 fields named `field`, `type`, and `value` with a constructor with single `String` argument as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.0.Final/userguide/html/StringConverter.html#d4e1570).

But it doesn't seem like resteasy is recognizing and parsing the `filters` query param? Is it possible to parse this type of nested array structure query parameters in resteasy?

```
  filters[0][field]=username&filters[0][type]=like&filters[0][value]=filteredB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still hoping that there's a better way, but here's a possible solution that works for me for now at least:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/myEndpoint")
 @Consumes("application/json")
 @Produces("application/json")
 public Response myEndpoint(@QueryParam("page") Integer page,
                            @QueryParam("size") Integer size,
                            @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    
    for(String key : uriInfo.getQueryParameters().keySet()) {
        
         // check if key starts with something like `filters[0]` 
         // and then parse it however you need. 
    }
 }
```